# Run find command from a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, find

Hi people: I'm making a xfe script to take a given directory as source file, use zenity to get output dir and perform some operations, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT_DIR=`zenity --file-selection --directory --filename="$1"`

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.wav" -exec bash -c 'oggenc -Q "$0" -q 3 "$OUTPUT_DIR/${0%.wav}.ogg"' {} \;
fi
```

When the script is invoked, oggenc is not executed...any ideas?

**Solution**: Based on answers bellow, this works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

OUTPUT_DIR=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --filename="$1")

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    export OUTPUT_DIR
    find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.wav" -exec sh -c 'oggenc -Q "$0" -q 3 -o "${OUTPUT_DIR}/$(basename "${0/.wav/.ogg}")"' {} \;
fi
zenity --info --text="Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the variable `$OUTPUT_DIR` available to the child process, add one line:

```
OUTPUT_DIR=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --filename="$1")
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    export OUTPUT_DIR
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.wav" -exec bash -c 'oggenc -Q "$0" -q 3 "$OUTPUT_DIR/${0%.wav}.ogg"' {} \;
fi
```

Or, slightly simpler:

```
if OUTPUT_DIR=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --filename="$1"); then
    export OUTPUT_DIR
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.wav" -exec bash -c 'oggenc -Q "$0" -q 3 "$OUTPUT_DIR/${0%.wav}.ogg"' {} \;
fi
```

Notes:

1. The command `'oggenc -Q "$0" -q 3 "$OUTPUT_DIR/${0%.wav}.ogg"'` appears in single-quotes.  This means that the variables are not expanded by the parent shell.  They are expanded by the child shell.  To make it available to the child shell, a variable must be exported.
2. `[ $? == 0 ]` works in bash but `[ $? = 0 ]` will also work and is more portable.
3. Command substitution can be done with backticks and some old shells only accept backticks.  For modern shells, however, the `$(...)` has the advantage of improved readability (some fonts don't clearly distinguish back and normal quotes).  Also `$(...)` can be nested in a clear and sensible way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use `while` loop over pipelining. Your code may be rewritten in this way

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
   oggenc -Q "${file}" -q 3 "${OUTPUT_DIR}/$(basename ${file/.wav/.ogg})"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.wav" -print0)
```

The reason why your code was not working is that single quotes `'` forbids variables expansion so `$OUTPUT_DIR` will not expand.

**EDIT**

*`-print0` is used in conjunction with `IFS=` is to split `find` output only on `\0` but not on whitespace in filenames.*

Comment: In your code, do I need to export `OUTPUT_DIR` before use it?

Comment: @Joel nope. it will expand normally in double quotes

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for pointing out. I've tested with wrong IFS. I'll fix it

Comment: Ok, using your updated code @vsminkov, `${OUTPUT_DIR}/${file/.wav/.ogg}` becomes something like this: **/home/XXX/Música/test/out//home/XXX/Música/test/in/ringout.ogg**

Comment: @Joel ok, I see. All you need is to use `basename`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Ah ok, but seems that is having trouble with filenames with spaces